# cx_Oracle Query Performance

Tags: python, oracle

I plan to use python at my job to connect directly to our main system production database. However the IT department is reluctant since apparently there is no easy way to control how much I can query the database. Hence they are worried I could affect performance for the rest of the users.

Is there a way to limit frequency of queries from python connection to the database? Or some other method that I can "sell" to my IT department so they will let me connect directly to production DB via python?

Many thanks

Comment: Your DBAs have never heard of [profiles](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310)? Or [Database Resource Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dbrm.htm#ADMIN027)?

Answer (score 2):

Database resource manager gives quite few options for this, depending how the production usage is compared to what you will be adding. This does not depend on the type of client.

https://blogs.oracle.com/db/oracle-resource-manager-and-dbmsresourcemanager

Often a plan is created where an order of usage limiting is specified. Regular production will get most resources, your project a class lower. If production is running, your session[s] get what is left over by production.

Also very nice is a cost estimation that allows to cancel a query deemed too expensive.

A bit of thought must be given to slow long running transaction that held blocking locks…. It does need a bit of experimentation to get this right.